# What [javascript] questions are on-topic?

Tags: discussion, tags, scope, clean-up

I've tweaked the tag guidance and description of the [javascript](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/javascript) tag to try to make it more clear that more than likely the question our visitor is about to ask is off-topic here.

As you can see, a lot of [javascript](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/javascript) questions have been closed. (There are many more which have subsequently been deleted.) The ones that haven't been closed probably should be, or should be looked at really hard as to whether they should retain the [javascript](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/javascript) tag.

The question for discussion is: What type of questions would be on-topic here where the [javascript](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/javascript) tag would be appropriate? So far, all I've got is questions about scripting in some Google apps, but that should be covered by [google-apps-script](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/google-apps-script).

---

Trying to drum up some visibility on this issue. I can't find a good reason to keep the JavaScript tag around, and plenty of good reasons to get rid of it (and possibly blacklist it): It keeps attracting programming questions.

Answer (score 7):

Bookmarklets for interacting with Web Apps are on topic according to the [tour](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/tour), and are written in JavaScript.

However, very few (two as of now) [bookmarklet](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/bookmarklet) questions have the JavaScript tag. So it seems the tag is mostly used for off-topic questions, which is a good reason to get rid of it.

Comment: I suggest that for those, the [tag:bookmarklet] should suffice.